# Pygame Subset for Android and utf-16-be encoding

Tags: python, android, pygame

I'm playing with RenPy's pygame for android and I encountered problem with unicode...

Even this simple script crashes:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

blah = u"żźć"

def main():
    pass
```

Here's what adb logcat is telling me:

```
I/python  ( 6957): Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 6957):   File "start.pyx", line 59, in init start (/home/tom/ab/pygame-droid/android-sdl/jni/../jni/application/src//start.c:1372)
I/python  ( 6957): LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-16-be
```

I know that it simply doesn't have this encoding, but why does it try to use utf-16-be at all? I'm saving it as utf-8 (using geany). Sorry, my English isn’t very good ><. Thanks in advance.

Comment: android does not use unicode like linux, they adopted icu, are you sure the python build supports unicode? you don't need u'' if you use utf8, just assign it to blah

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `'\x'` and `chr()` for weird characters.

```
chr(83)='S'='\x53'
ord('S')=83
```

Both [chr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) and [ord](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) are built in python functions.

Once you find the number for those odd characters it might work.